# racket/base namespace

Tags: scheme, racket, r7rs

Anyone know what is included in the `racket/base` language. I am looking to compare the `racket/base` namespace definitions with the R7RS draft to get a first hand idea of how divergent Racket is from Scheme.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is going to be *huge*, just like any other practical Scheme implementation.  To give you a rough idea, I see more than 1300 identifiers from `racket/base`, and `racket` goes up to over 2000.  Also, note that comparing the names is not going to be the whole story -- there are additional differences, like the fact that Racket uses immutable pairs by default, and like the fact that you get guaranteed left-to-right evaluation order.

A quick way to get the lists yourself for the former would be to make sure that [XREPL](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xrepl/) is installed (have your `~/.racketrc` file contain `(require xrepl)`), then start Racket with `racket/base` as the REPL language, and use the [`,ap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xrepl/#%28xrepl._apropos%29) (apropos) command with no arguments so it shows you all of the bound names:

```
$ racket -I racket/base
Welcome to Racket v5.2.1.
-> ,ap
```

To read about the names, you can use the [`,doc`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xrepl/#%28xrepl._doc%29) command, or just use the [search box](http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/) in the docs.

Comment: Straight to the point answer and by the way, the r7rs draft looks like a practical language.

Comment: "Practical" is a relative term...  It's more practical than r5rs, but it won't have threads, subprocesses, network, non-blocking IO, and a gazillion other things, so the difference is huge.  Even the big language will not have all of these.

Answer (score 1):

According to [The Racket Reference](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/index.html):

> Unless otherwise noted, the bindings defined in this manual are exported by the racket/base and racket languages.

Unfortunately that is not terribly helpful since it is a large reference manual. But, since you are comparing R7RS to Racket, it may be useful to just browse through the whole reference to get an idea of what is available.